# Header and Footer Css

Tags: css, 960.gs

I have researching on web page dimensions and i have since settled on grid 960px. However i don't understand one thing on headers and footers.Take for instance stackoverflow's header that houses the username | logout | chat | meta | about | faq and the search box.It runs end to end of the browser.How can i make my header run end to end in css?.

Thanks.

Comment: you could check the header of stackoverflow with firebug :) so you can see how it is done.

Comment: +1 I can't remember life without FireBug

Comment: What was life like before Firebug?

Comment: @benhowdle89: There was *life* then?

Comment: Life was like this: http://www2.warnerbros.com/spacejam/movie/jam.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css:

```
#header {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
}
#middle {
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
background-color: blue;
}
#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: green;
}
```

This is just the relevant bits, not the entire CSS code :)

Comment: Hi ben,i followed your example and googled width: 100px and i was lucky to nail what i was exactly after.http://www.cssgirl.com/resources/2008/06/07/create-full-width-header-footer-with-centered-content-using-css/

Comment: You did mean width: 100%, not width: 100px didnt you?

Answer (score 0):

960.gs is just a "blueprint" to work from. Probably better to learn the basics before you dive in to a grid based system.

SO just uses a negative margin:

```
#custom-header {
    background-color: #EEE;
    height: 31px;
    margin-bottom: -31px;
}
```

before a `<div id="header"></div>`, which is a 960px wide centered div.

Answer (score 0):

## Try This

```
@media print {
    @page {
        margin-top:0;
        margin-bottom:0;
        margin-top:initial;
    }
}
```